# Display features product on category page

Tags: prestashop

I am looking to display the characteristics of a product under prestashop in the category page on each product thumbnail display. Do you have any idea how is it possible to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In file \themes\default-bootstrap\product-list.tpl there is

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
```

After that add this:

```
{$product|@print_r}
```

Then You have all product data with characteristics. This code above dispaly all variable which is return by controller. You just need to display what You want.

Comment: I already try but it does not show the characteristics in the page category.

Comment: by characteristics you mean product attributes ?

Comment: {$product.features|@print_r}

Answer (score 0):

its ok solution like this:

```
<div class="features">
                        {foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
                            {if $feature.name == 'Contenance'}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span><img src="{$img_dir}arrow-right-purple-2.png"
                                               class="left_arrow"/>{$feature.value}</span>
                                </div>
                            {/if}
                            {if $feature.name == 'Couleur'}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span><img src="{$img_dir}arrow-right-purple-2.png"
                                               class="left_arrow"/>{$feature.value}</span>
                                </div>
                            {/if}
                        {/foreach}
                    </div>
```

Thanks